# Count Data each shift schedule

Tags: oracle, query

Hi i'm trying to write query that will give me the count of duration that is greater than 10 each employee per Shift schedule.

```
Shift A - 6AM - 2PM
Shift B - 2PM - 10PM
Shift C - 10PM - 6AM
```

tbleventlogs

```
EVENTID     USERID      DATE_TIME   READERID                 READERNAME LOGTYPE   RESULT DURATION

188110074       50078       2020-03-02 22:01:31 544381441       LOCKER      IN   00:12  12
188099752       50078       2020-03-02 21:48:52 544381436       LOCKER      OUT             
188098672       50078       2020-03-02 21:47:10 544381441       LOCKER      IN              
188098656       50078       2020-03-02 21:47:06 544381441       LOCKER      IN   15:45  945
187972279       50078       2020-03-02 06:01:54 544381436       LOCKER      OUT             
187949027       50078       2020-03-02 04:30:46 544381441       LOCKER      IN   00:16  16
187933475       50078       2020-03-01 22:44:47 544381431       LOCKER      IN   00:04  4
187933289       50078       2020-03-01 22:40:41 544381436       LOCKER      OUT             
187926256       50078       2020-03-01 22:01:31 544381431       LOCKER      IN   00:14  14
187914503       50078       2020-03-01 21:46:42 544381428       LOCKER      OUT  
180769437       1214201592  2020-01-20 08:13:06 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  
180771730       1214201592  2020-01-20 08:36:38 544381431       LOCKER      IN   00:23  23
180775099       1214201592  2020-01-20 09:07:04 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  
180777340       1214201592  2020-01-20 09:30:53 544381431       LOCKER      IN   00:23  23
180778948       1214201592  2020-01-20 09:48:58 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  
180781714       1214201592  2020-01-20 10:04:52 544381431       LOCKER      IN   00:15  15
```

tblemployeegroup

```
EMPLOYEEID  EMPLOYEENAME        GROUPCODE   

050078      ARCIAGA,        SC-G3-4G                    
1214201592  CALMA, VILMA LARIN  ASSR2*              
003502      ORRICA, MARY MELIN  ACBA1
```

tblshiftsched

```
SHIFTCODE   DATESHIFT       STARTSHIFT                      ENDSHIFT                                ISRESTDAY

SC-G3-4G           1/24/2020        1/1/1970 2:00:00.000000 PM  1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM              0
SC-G3-4G        1/25/2020       1/1/1970 2:00:00.000000 PM  1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM              0
SC-G3-4G        1/26/2020       1/1/1970 2:00:00.000000 PM  1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM             0
SC-G3-4G        1/27/2020       1/1/1970 2:00:00.000000 PM  1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM             0
SC-G3-4G        2/10/2020       1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM 1/1/1970 6:00:00.000000 AM              0
SC-G3-4G        2/11/2020       1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM 1/1/1970 6:00:00.000000 AM              0
SC-G3-4G        2/12/2020       1/1/1970 10:00:00.000000 PM 1/1/1970 6:00:00.000000 AM              0
```

i able to count data but its by each date and my problem is i only capture Shift A and Shift B because i get the data per day and Shift C takes 2 day

```
 SELECT   a.userid, a.username,
            TRUNC (TO_DATE (a.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                  ) AS date_time,
            COUNT (a.DURATION) COUNT
       FROM tblaccesslogs a
      WHERE DURATION > 10
   GROUP BY a.username,
            a.userid,
            TRUNC (TO_DATE (a.date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Note this is related to my previous question [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500302/count-data-each-days/60500368?noredirect=1#comment107030484_60500368)

Hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Replace source tables with according CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: What is the data type of column `date_time`?

Comment: on tbleventlogs its varchar2 then the other is timestamp

Comment: count the duration greater than 10 base on his shift from tblshiftsched, the main concern is the shift C spans 2 days